# key listener with acm.graphics

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-events, keylistener, acm.graphics

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264915/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-mouselistener-when-using-acm-graphics).

I have a game built in the [ACM Graphics Library](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/). I want to be able to pause the game upon a keypress of the **P key**. However I've looked in the documentation and there seems to be a mention of key listeners briefly but no actual examples of them in use in this context (unless I've missed something).

I don't want to use a **console or dialogue box** as I don't want to enter data via the keyboard, I just want to be able to toggle my pause method on and off using the **P key** within my main game loop. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would the KeyListener be any different with whatever ACM graphics?? Have you searched the myriads of references for KeyListener???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class that subclasses ACM's `Program` to add a key listener to. Secondly, you need a class that implements `KeyListener` (this could be the same class) and then do your code in `KeyListener#keyPressed`. You can get the pressed key's code via `KeyEvent.getKeyCode` and check whether it equals your desired key (in this case the P key).

The following example illustrates how this may work. It didn't test it, but it should do the trick.

```java
public class KeyListenerExample extends GraphicsProgram {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        addKeyListeners(new MyKeyListener());
    }

    private class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                System.out.println("Key 'P' has been pressed!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }

    }
}
```

It would be helpful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question (especially for further questions).