# How to add keyboard listeners into GraphicsProgram

Tags: java

So I want to make a shooting game where an object shoots stuff and I want to add keyboard listeners(wasd, arrow keys). Can anyone tell me what is the best way to implement keyboard listeners? My final objective is too be able to move the green circle by using the keyboard as well(WASD and arrow keys).

```
import acm.graphics.*; 
import acm.program.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
public class survivor2 extends GraphicsProgram { 
   
  
  
  public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 800;
  public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 500;
  
  
  
  GOval redBall, greenball; 
  GObject gobj; 
  GLabel timeLabel;
  GRectangle redBallbox, greenballbox;
   
  double lastX, lastY; 
  int redBallXJump, redBallYJump, time, leveltime, speed;

  
  final int DIAM = 50;
  final int WAIT = 2;
  
  
  public void init( ) { 
    
    
    time = 0;
    leveltime = 0;
    timeLabel = new GLabel("Time survived: " + time);
    timeLabel.setFont("*-BOLD-16");
    add(timeLabel, 0, 16);
    timeLabel.setVisible(false);
    
    redBallXJump = 1;
    redBallYJump = 1;
    
    speed = 1;
    
    redBall = new GOval(1, 1, DIAM, DIAM); 
    redBall.setFilled(true); 
    redBall.setColor(Color.RED); 
    add(redBall); 
    greenball = new GOval(300, 115, 100, 70); 
    greenball.setFilled(true); 
    greenball.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
    add(greenball); 
    
    
    addMouseListeners( ); 
    waitForClick();
    
    
    
  } //init 
  
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
    lastX = e.getX( ); 
    lastY = e.getY( ); 
    gobj = getElementAt(lastX, lastY); 
    if (gobj != null) { 
      gobj.sendToFront(); } 
  } //mousePressed 
  
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) { 
    if (gobj != null) { 
      int xDisplacement = (int) (m.getX( ) - lastX); 
      int yDisplacement = (int) (m.getY( ) - lastY); 
gobj.move(xDisplacement, yDisplacement); 
lastX = m.getX( ); 
lastY = m.getY( ); } 
} //mouseDragged 
public void run( ) { 
  
  
  while(true){
    
    GRectangle redBallbox = redBall.getBounds();
    GRectangle greenballbox = greenball.getBounds();
    
    
    pause(WAIT);
    time = time + WAIT;
    leveltime = leveltime + WAIT;
    
    if (leveltime == 10000){
      
          
          
    }
    
    
          if (redBallbox.intersects(greenballbox)==true){
            timeLabel.setVisible(true);
            timeLabel.setLabel("Time survived: " + time/1000+ " seconds");
            break;
          }
    
    
        if (redBall.getY( ) <= 0) //at top of window?
            {
                 redBallYJump = 1;
            }
        else if (redBall.getY( )+DIAM >= APPLICATION_HEIGHT) //at bottom?
            {
                 redBallYJump = -1;
            }
        else if (redBall.getX( ) <= 0) //at left?
            {
                 redBallXJump = 1;
            }
         else if (redBall.getX( )+DIAM >= APPLICATION_WIDTH) //at right?
            {
                 redBallXJump = -1;
            }
         redBall.move(redBallXJump, redBallYJump);     
    
    
  }
    
      
    
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [key listener with acm.graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714167/key-listener-with-acm-graphics)

You essentially just have to copy this code into your class:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    addKeyListeners(new MyKeyListener());
}

private class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
            System.out.println("Key 'P' has been pressed!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }

}
```

Handle the key presses inside the `keyPressed()` function.